# Add composition variables?

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer

Is there any 'easy' way to alter or add custom variables in a QGIS Composition in a Python script?

Setting a project variable can be done with `QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable`, but is there any method like that for composition variables?

Comment: just look at this method https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsExpressionContextUtils.html#abbefea950067911714f53f1b8a05e336